# GWT 2.1 RequestFactory multi level relation population

Tags: gwt, request, relationship, gwt2

I'm using GWT 2.1 along with its RequestFactory. I understand, using the with() methode on a request for an object A, enables me to populate relations so that I can access B1 and B2 from A. Is it possible to populate relations beyond level 1 so that I can access C1 and C2 from A via B1, B2?

```
        A
        |
    ---------
    |       |
    B1      B2
    |       |
    C1      C2
```

Answer (score 2):

The "dot notation" does the trick. Using `... with("B1", "B1.C1") ...` gives access to C1.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the GWT Editor framework, you can generate the argument for the `with()` call by using [`RequsetFactoryEditorDelegate.getPaths()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/requestfactory/client/RequestFactoryEditorDriver.html#getPaths%28%29)